# How do i store data from HTTPREAD into a variable?

Tags: http, arduino, iot, gsm

I need a way to store HTTPREAD data into a variable because I will be comparing its value to another variable. Is there any way?

```
  {
  myGsm.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://7ae0eae2.ngrok.io/get-ignition/ccb37bd2-a59e-4e56-a7e1-68fd0d7cf845"); // Send PARA command
  myGsm.print("\"\r\n"); 
  delay(1000);
  printSerialData();

  myGsm.println();
  myGsm.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");//submit the GET request 
  delay(8000);//the delay is important if the return datas are very large, the time required longer.
  printSerialData();
  myGsm.println("AT+HTTPREAD=0,17");// read the data from the website you access
  delay(3000);
  printSerialData();
  delay(1000);
}

void printSerialData()
{
 while(myGsm.available()!=0)
 Serial.write(myGsm.read());
}
```

Comment: What the `AT+HTTPREAD=0,17` returns?

Comment: Do you want to store some value into a variable comming from the `myGsm.read()`?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the `Serial.write(myGsm.read())` is *where you want to get the data from*. In other words, you are receiving the data through the serial connection, and you want to parse the data returned from the `AT+HTTPREAD` command.

Since you *did not provide* any clue about what that command is returning in the serial, I gonna use as an example a different command that I know the output, the below one:

```
TX=> AT+CCLK?
RX=> AT+CCLK?\n\r
     \t+CCLK: "2020/03/03, 22:00:14"\n\r
```

So, the string you are going to get from the above `AT+CCLK?` command is this (I am assigning to a char pointer for the sake of understanding):

```c
char *answer = "AT+CCLK?\n\r\t+CCLK: "2020/03/03, 22:00:14"\n\r";
```

What you need is to parse the answer (the `char *answer` in this example) to get the *"numbers"* into variables.

How to do that?

You need to walk over that string, moving to specific places. For example, to be able to convert the `2020` into a variable, you need to be at position `answer[19]`, and then you can use, let's say, the `strtoul()` to convert to an integer and store it into a variable.

```c
uint32_t year = strtoul(&answer[19], NULL, 10);
```

Then, to get the month, you need to walk a bit more to reach the position at the month on the string:

```c
uint32_t month = strtoul(&answer[24], NULL, 10);
```

And so on, but you are using *magic numbers* for that, in other words, the numbers *19*, *24* are positions specific for this string.

Then, how to make this "walking" smarter?

You can use tokens in conjunction with the `strstr()` to go to the specific points you want in the string. In this case, we want to move the pointer to the first `2`, so we can pass that pointer to the `strtoul()` to convert it into an integer.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    char *answer = "AT+CCLK?\n\r\t+CCLK: "2020/03/03, 22:00:14"\n\r";
    char *token = "CCLK: \"";
    char *ptr;
    uint32_t year;

    ptr = strstr(answer, token);

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Token not found\n");
        return -1;
    }

    year = strtoul(++ptr, NULL, 10);
    printf("Year = %d\n", year);
```

Then, to make this code into a function to be more generic, here it is:

```c
    bool parse_answer_to_uint32(char *buff, char *tokens[], uint32_t *val)
    {
        char *ptr;
        int i;

        if (val == NULL)
            return false;


        for (i = 0; buff != NULL && tokens[i] != NULL; i++) {
            ptr = strstr(buff, tokens[i]);
            if (ptr == NULL)
                return false;
            buff = (ptr + strlen(tokens[i]));
        }
        // Here, you reached the point you want, based on the tokens you seek
        if (buff == NULL)
            return false;

        *val = strtoul(buff, NULL, 10);
    }
```

So, you can be able to call this function like this:

```
    char *tokens[] = { "CCLK: \"" };
    uint32_t year;

    if (parse_answer_to_uint32(myGsm.read().c_str(), tokens, &year) == false)
        return -1;
    printf("year is = %d\n", year);
```

The `printf` will print `2020` based on the example above.

This function is pretty flexible and generic enough. All you need is to pass different tokens to reach different points of the string and reach the value you want.

Comment: I didn't understand a single thing.

Comment: I edited, please check if it is understandable now. If not, please be more specific what you did not understand.

Answer (score -2):

Take character buffer, Concat data comming from serial into this buffer, and process that buffer for comparison.

Comment: I would use the `strstr()` to find for specific tokens and reach the point you want right before the value needed.

Comment: could you please explain it in more detail or write me a sample code